# Making TT-RSS cache images

Tags: linux, cache, rss, apache-http-server

Due to Google Reader's untimely demise, I've installed tiny-tiny RSS on my Linux machine under Apache 2. It's mostly a good enough replacement and I can at least go back to reading RSS feeds in my web browser at work.

Can I configure or hack TT-RSS to cache all the images it finds in its feeds? There is an option when adding a feed, but it doesn't seem to actually do anything. If I view (for example) today's XKCD comic in TT-RSS it still loads the image from the XKCD website. What I want is the image to be cached in TT-RSS and served from there instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click a feed and choose **Edit feed**, there is an option you can enable called *Cache images locally*. This should use [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) to cache the images locally (pre-1.7.0, you could edit your config file to use either SimplePie or [Magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) but Magpie has long since died as a project) and place them in your *cache/images* directory.

I've tested and confirmed that this feature works (I used XKCD's RSS Feed to test).

However, the one downside is that I think you have to enable this for feeds one-by-one as I could not find any switch to enable this globally.

If you want to cache images in starred articles specifically, there is a plugin that you can enable in **Preferences > Plugins** called *cache_starred_images*. I use this already and can confirm that it works.